# Steps to take for figuring out the delay when calling service and loading data with the result?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, silverlight, client-server

In a client server app, where client front end is done in silverlight using C# and the services are the WCF services.

If I am to hit the service and do a query and bring back a result and I notice that it is taking a relatively long time to load my page which is just loading the grid with the data, what things should I look at fix this issue or how would I fix this issue? What steps could I take to determine the problem? where is the bottle-neck, can anyone know from the little information provided here?

Does this have anything to do with serialization? Any insight on what could be causing this delay? My service calls are made async.

I hope this question makes sense :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible causes--you need to start with some basic troubleshooting and provide the results if you want any real guidance.  Start by stepping though the code with your debugger and finding out what line(s) of code are taking a long time to run.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do it get [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) on the client machine and run it.  Observing the actual conversations the client is having with the server is usually very informative.